# Drupal 8 - Social Login

Tags: authentication, facebook-social-plugins, drupal-8, twitter-login

Is there any free social login modules (for twitter and facebook) available for drupal 8? I have checked OpenID Connect module, but it does not support facebook and twitter logins. Please advice, if there are any stable modules available for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use oneAll social login. It covers 25+ social networks and works well. Download [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_login)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different modules

- social_auth_facebook
- social_auth_twitter

Which are based on `social_api` and `social_auth` modules. Create app in twitter and facebook and get the app_id and secret key and configure them under configuration> Social API Setting> Twitter/Facebook

Answer (score 0):

For facebook login module in d8 you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect

For twitter login https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter.
But twitter module is in dev version so it is not  functional yet.You can take inspiration from d7 version and try to upgrade